# not empty categories don't show in menu

Tags: categories, pages, get-posts

I'm trying to resolve a problem i have showing category posts. 
I have added a category to my main menu, eventhough it has posts - in the basic theme it doesn't show, in my theme - it shows as a link but when i click on it, shows just a blank page. 
I tried resetting the permalinks, clearing the cache... nothing.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be. I'm getting a bit desperate. 
Any help  will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to 2011. Does it still happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i tried both. it was still hapenning. at the end i discovered it was an error coming from the index.php - one line of code i had added following a tutorial which i forgot to remove after. removing it brought everything back to normal. sorry to bother, but it might help someone else.